# How do I enable the touchpad on a MacbookPro8,1?

Tags: 11.10, touchpad, macbook

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 in MacbookPro8,1. I can't enable touchpad, how to enable?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get to the menu's find the mouse/touchpad settings in the `system-settings`. You can also talk to it via the command-line using `synclient`. So for instance `synclient TouchpadOff=0` could switch back on the touchpad (if that was causing it). If it doesn't work or it complains with some errors, try to unload/reload the driver:

I made a small script that I've put in `~/bin` (for instance `reset_mouse`) and made executable with `chmod u+x ~/bin/reset_mouse`. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
device="bcm5974" ;
xterm -e "sudo modprobe -r $device && sudo modprob $device"
```

You might have another device (this is mine on my Macbook Pro 6,2). You can Google it or search via `lsmod`.

Hope this helps.